# Do static / relative divs accept height in %

Tags: html, css

I have a div which needs to be positioned statically / relatively. When it has both height and width defined in %, the browser (FF) ignores the height set and renders a very small div. However, when I set the height in px (approximately same calculated value), it works smoothly.

The width defined in % works perfectly.

I need the height to be defined in % as well - due to resolution / scaling issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `height`s of all ancestors of your `div`.

Comment: Can all ancestors have heights in % ?

Comment: If they ancestors are `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: Yes they can. If the parentmost (`html`) element is measured in %, the base height is the height of your browser window.

Comment: Percent heights require the height of the immediate parent. If that ancestor is also a percent, then it also needs the parent to have a height and so on.

Answer (score 3):

From http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/height :

> Percentage values refer to the height
>   of the element’s containing block. If
>   the height of the containing block
>   isn’t specified explicitly (that is,
>   it depends on content height), and
>   this element isn’t absolutely
>   positioned, the percentage value is
>   treated as auto. A percentage value is
>   also treated as auto for table cells,
>   table rows, and row groups.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Also, be aware of [different browser behaviors](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) when using percent values.
(For example, just because 4x25% equals 100%, does not mean that your divs will take 100%.)

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate percents by manipulating the pixel heights of elements with JavaScript.